# Excel export not working on Firefox but working fine in google crome

Tags: javascript, html, export-to-excel

The below given event is called to export the data in the table into an EXCEL , The code works like a charm in Chrome . In IE and Firefox i am not getting anything(File, error etc).
Kindly assist me to go forward and export the file in all the browsers

```
$("[id$=myButtonControlID]").click(function(e) { 
    var result = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + encodeURIComponent($('div[id$=printHead]').html());
    var link = document.createElement("a");
    link.download = "Reports";
    link.href = result;
    link.click();
});
```

Comment: Please specify what exactly is "not working".

Comment: I am not able to export the specified content into Excel

Comment: You should try to be more specific. Are there any error messages? Is no file retrieved? Has the file the wrong format? Does Excel show an error message when opening the file? etc.

Comment: No error message is logged or shown , the same code works perfectly on google chrome , As i click the export button the specified content gets auto downloaded as a excel file . Which is not happening in Firefox , just a page refresh is occurred as this function is called

Comment: I believe i can get some help now

Comment: Firefox version : 44.0b1, Chrome : 55.0.2883.87 , No error message logged and 'application/vnd.ms-excel' is registered in Firefox

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With Firefox you have to explicitly add the `link` element to the DOM before you can execute `.click()`:

```
$("[id$=myButtonControlID]").click(function(e) { 
    var result = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + encodeURIComponent($('div[id$=printHead]').html());
    var link = document.createElement("a");
    document.body.appendChild(link);  // You need to add this line
    link.download = "Reports";
    link.href = result;
    link.click();
});
```

The `data:` URI is supported from IE8. But it "cannot be used for navigation [...]" so I assume it will not work in an `<a href="...">`. See [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc848897).

Comment: The problem still exists in IE  version :10.0.9200.17414

Comment: @chandrahasan Does IE 10 support the data: URI?

Comment: I believe IE 8.0 and above supports it

Comment: @chandrahasan I have neither IE8 nor IE10 over here. I created a static `a` element in an html: `<a href="data:application/vnd.ms-excel,test" download="Reports">Download</a>`. With IE11 this link leads to the error message "Internet Explorer can not display the webpage".

Comment: @chandrahasan The `data:` URI is supported from IE8. But it "cannot be used for navigation [...]" so I assume it will not work in an `<a href=`. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc848897(v=vs.85).aspx