# export to excel file not working in firefox

Tags: javascript

I am using below javascript to export data to excel file.below script is working fine in chrome(file is getting downloaded) but file is not getting downloaded and no errors are also coming in firefox console(I see this message 'Successfully downloaded excel.' in firefox console).

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
                            req.open("POST", "xxxxx/exportapi/exportmetadata", true);  //calling Rest API   
                            req.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
                            req.responseType  = "blob";  
                            req.onload = function(e) {
                                if (this.status == 200) {
                                     var blob = this.response;
                                     var downloadLink = domConstruct.create("a", {
                                            href: window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([blob], { type: 'application/vnd.ms-excel' })),
                                            download: "ExportExcelDataList.xlsx"
                                         });
                                         downloadLink.click();

                                         console.log('Successfully downloaded excel.')
                                 }
                                 else {
                                    console.log('Unable to download excel.')
                                }
                              };
                            req.send(json);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
```

before

```
downloadLink.click();
```

For reference, view the given link  [Excel export not working on Firefox but working fine in google crome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41805095/excel-export-not-working-on-firefox-but-working-fine-in-google-crome/41806544)